# Getting nan when making a dataframe column equal to another

Tags: python, pandas

I am trying to make a subset of a dataframe

```
combo.iloc[:,orig_start_col:orig_start_col+2]
```

equal to the values another subset already has

```
combo.iloc[:,sm_col:sm_col+2]
```

where the columns will vary in a loop. The problem is that all I am getting is NaNs despite that the second subset values are not NaN

I tried to do this for the first column and it worked, however doing so with just the second column of the subset returns all NaNs. Then doing for the whole subset returns Nan values for everything

My code is:

```
for node_col in ('leg2_node', 'leg4_node'):
    combo=orig_combos.merge(all, how='inner', left_on='leg6_node', right_on=node_col)
    combo.reset_index(drop=True, inplace=True)
    orig_start_col=combo.columns.get_loc('leg6_alpha_x')
    sm_col=combo.columns.get_loc(node_col+'_y')
    combo.iloc[:,orig_start_col+1:orig_start_col+2]=combo.
    iloc[:,sm_col+1:sm_col+2]
```

What I would expect having sm_col:sm_col+2 subset all rows with values is to have those values in orig_start_col:orig_start_col+2 subset, but instead what I am having is all values=NaN

Comment: This is almost certainly an index alignment issue. `pandas` will align on the Index, so  even though your shapes are the same, if the column headers are different (which is likely the case given one is indexed with `orig_start_col` and the other with `sm_col`) the index is mismatched, so everything gets filled with `NaN`. Try adding a `.to_numpy()` at the end of your `combo` slice on the RHS of the last line. This then just requires the shapes to match, since the numpy array has no index.

Comment: I tried this and actually it worked amazing (it worked with .values as well) but I still don't understand why indexes are misaligned if its the same dataframe. Do you know where could I get more info on the subject?

Comment: I'll try to find a post to link, otherwise I can add an explanation. The main point is that there is both an Index for rows (the row labels) and columns (the column labels) When doing DataFrame = DataFrame, both the rows and columns need to have the same labels. But when doing DataFrame = np.ndarray it's just a shape match.